# If statement return functions

Tags: php

```
 function isEqual($number1, $number2, $sum){

$total = $number1 + $number2;
    if ($total = $sum){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isEqual(5,5,8)){
echo 'Sum!';
}
else {
    echo 'No sum!';
    }
```

PHP

My homework assignment says the if-clause is supposed to be just like that. So when $total is NOT equal to $sum it's supposed to say: No sum!.

The thing is I shouldn't change the if, I have to change something in my function because it's always saying 'Sum!' right now.

Can someone help me with this? It's not supposed to be difficult but I can't find it on google.

Comment: Please, specify the programming language!

Comment: Aaaaaaand you deleted the code...

Comment: I've no idea what I am doing :P it 's solved by now thanks everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $total == $sum instead of $total = $sum.

'=' is assignment and '==' is comparation

Answer (score 1):

You used `$total = $sum` instead of `$total == $sum` and therefore made an assignment rather than a comparison.

The value of an assignment expression is the value of the assigned value so it will always be true unless the assigned value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using the assignment operator ("=") in your conditional (if statement).

Try using the equality ("==", or double equals) operator to test for equality.